# How to setup a smart oneliner for calculating with very large data?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, loops

I have masked arrays for latitude (`Xpos`) and longitude(`Ypos`) with dimensions (**`125,800,000`**).

I want to calculate the difference in latitude and longitude within the arrays. Here's the array `Xpos` (`Ypos` is similar).

```
 masked_array(  data       = [ [-2.0551843643188477, -2.637551784515381, -2.720881223678589,  ..., 2.2812530994415283, 2.281250476837158, 2.281254768371582 ],
                               [-2.3242127895355225, -2.804257869720459, -2.8825504779815674, ..., 2.2812530994415283, 2.281250476837158, 2.281254768371582 ],
                               [-2.073770523071289, -2.6198980808258057, -2.708889961242676,  ..., 2.2812530994415283, 2.281250476837158, 2.281254768371582 ],
                               ...,
                               [-3.517531633377075, -2.908338785171509, -2.9069409370422363,  ..., 2.2812530994415283, 2.281250476837158, 2.281254768371582 ],
                               [-3.688690662384033, -3.0086288452148438, -3.010164260864258,  ..., 2.2812530994415283, 2.281250476837158, 2.281254768371582 ],
                               [-3.520817518234253, -2.943941116333008, -2.941941738128662,   ..., 2.2812530994415283, 2.281250476837158, 2.281254768371582 ]
                               ],
                mask       = [ [ False, False, False, ..., False, False, False ],
                               [ False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
                               [ False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
                               ...,
                               [ False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
                               [ False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
                               [ False, False, False, ..., False, False, False]
                               ],
                fill_value = 1e+20,
                dtype      = float32
                )
```

---

This is my code, which works, but takes super long to compute.

```
Dist= np.zeros((len(XposApr),len(XposApr[0])))
DiffLon=np.zeros((len(XposApr),len(XposApr[0])))
DiffLat=np.zeros((len(XposApr),len(XposApr[0])))
for i in range (1,len(XposApr),12):
    for j in range (0,len(XposApr[0])):
        DiffLon[i][j]=(XposApr[i][j]-XposApr[i-1][j])
        DiffLat[i][j]=(YposApr[i][j]-YposApr[i-1][j])
```

I don't really know how to make the famous one-liners, this is what I tried, but does not work:

```
DistLon = [XposApr[i][j]-XposApr[i-1][j] for i in enumerate (XposApr) and j in enumerate (XposApr[0])]
```

Is it possible to make a oneliner or another code which makes the calculation a lot faster?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know if a oneliner is necessarily going to be faster just by virtue of being only one line. Probably using things like numpy [vector operations](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/quickstart.html#basic-operations) would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Is it possible to make a oneliner or another **code which makes the calculation a lot faster**?*

### <sup>Syntax-format is not the core for achieving the speed,</sup>
 Smart vectorisations or re-formulations are:

Until the glorious **`numba`**-team decides to move the support for masked-array operations onto a front burner, there is lack of JIT-accelerated speeds coming from `numba.jit( ... )` ( [Masked array support #2103](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/2103) )

So let's try with `numpy`-native steps:

The inner loop may get out of slow, GIL-driven motion first:

```
for     i in range ( 1, len( XposApr    ), 12 ):
    #or j in range ( 0, len( XposApr[0] )     ):
        DiffLon[i][:] = ( XposApr[i][:] - XposApr[i-1][:] )
        DiffLat[i][:] = ( YposApr[i][:] - YposApr[i-1][:] )
```

Yet, if I read the layout correctly, the whole may get solved in both dimensions by going into something like this:

```
 DiffLon[1:len( XposApr ):12] = ( XposApr[1:len( XposApr   ):12]
                                - XposApr[0:len( XposApr )-1:12]
                                  )
 DiffLat[1:len( XposApr ):12] = ( YposApr[1:len( XposApr   ):12]
                                - YposApr[0:len( XposApr )-1:12]
                                  )
```

And I am sure either [@Divakar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3293881/divakar) or [@cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4909087/c%E1%B4%8F%CA%9F%E1%B4%85s%E1%B4%98%E1%B4%87%E1%B4%87%E1%B4%85), the true `numpy`-gurus here will get ready to tell you even smarter and more efficient slicing/vectorising tricks for doing the same, so be patient :o)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers and to @patrick for the usefull comment, I believe this might also solve my problem:

```
Xapr=np.array(XposApr)
Yapr=np.array(YposApr)
for i in range (1,len(XposApr)):
    DiffLon[i]=(Xapr[i]-Xapr[i-1])
    DiffLat[i]=(Yapr[i]-Yapr[i-1])
```